# How does SLURM array Interface with SBATCH resource allocation?

Tags: linux, slurm, sbatch

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p RM-shared
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH -t 24:00:00
#SBATCH --array=1-
```

I am trying to start an array and for each task in the array I would like it to use 4 cores on the RM-shared partition. Am I doing this correctly or does this designate that ALL of the tasks output by the array with have to share 4 cores?

I will ask a separate question for this, but for some reason when I run this, the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` variable is empty....

when I run

```
echo "My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: " $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

after my headers setting up the job, it returns

```
My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID:
```

Comment: I realized that I should use
`#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4` and not `-n 4` I think (?)
However, this did not solve my $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID beign empty issue

Comment: Resources: (1) https://hpc-support.lboro.ac.uk/slurm-nodes-cpus-tasks.html

(2) https://login.scg.stanford.edu/faqs/cores/

"Slurm complicates this, however, by using the terms core and cpu interchangeably depending on the context and Slurm command. --cpus-per-taks= for example is actually specifying the number of cores per task."

Answer (score 1):

First you are right about using `--cpus-per-task=4`  rather than `ntasks`. Second, it could be a copy/paste error, but your `--array` line is incomplete

```
#SBATCH --array=1-
```

should be

```
#SBATCH --array=1-10
```

for instance for a 10-job array.

Each job in the array will have 4 distinct cores allocated to it. And the job will be scheduled independently, so they could for instance start all 10 on a 40-core nodes at the same time, or on 10 distinct nodes at the same time, or on one 4-core nodes one at a time, or any possible in-between combination depending on the cluster configuration and jobs in the queue.

Comment: someone at the help desk of the system I am using (XSEDE's PSC HTC cluster resources), told me I should not use `--cpus-per-task=4 ` but rather `--cpus-per-task=4` ... see my answer to my own question here, would love to hear your input if you had any.

Comment: yes, you are right about the `#SBATCH --array=1-` I erroneously somehow thought this would set the array length to a undefined "maxlength" such that it would stop once it reaches the end of what the array is iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt calling the script properly. was calling:
`./ThisScript.sh`
instead of
`sbatch ./ThisScript.sh`

Regarding the allocation of cores per array job, a helpdesk person said to use
`#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4`
instead of
`#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4`

but I do not know why... I would expect `--ntasks-per-node=4` to command that each node needed only run 4 jobs, so if you had 12 jobs in your array it would require 3 full nodes.

`--cpus-per-task=4` on the other hand, would command that each CPU (each with hosts a number of cores) would only run 4 tasks, so if you had 12 jobs in your array, it would requre 3 CPUs (and, if the nodes on your system have 3 or more CPUs, it would only require 1 node).